# Show tooltip to a tag with particular class on mousehover in angular

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, angular

I have **innerhtml** content as a string in **component ts** file under the variable **text**. So I am displaying that in my html file (In the UI). Some of the **htmlcontent** contains a span tag with a class named highlight. What i want is that when I hover my mouse over the highlight class I have to get a tooltip.

Note: I can't hardcode any values manually into the variable text's html content. Instead I have to find a way to show a tooltip when the class under the span tag is highlight (which shows the words as red color).

This is my string or innerhtml content in the ts file. It is stored in variable named text.

```
 '<span class="highlight" >It is a long</span> established fact that a <span class="highlight">re</span><span class="highlight"></span><span class="highlight">ader </span>will be distracted by the <span class="highlight">readable content </span>of a page when <span class="highlight">look</span><span class="highlight"></span><span class="highlight">ing </span>at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum';
```

[my stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zc1zzq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: you should look at angular material. Refer https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tooltip-material

Comment: yea but I dont know how to apply to that particular class alone. can u please show that on stackblitz @ShashankVivek

Answer (score 0):

You can use **AfterViewInit** in angular and get the required span elements using classname **getElementsbyClassname**. loop through those elements and create and append a **tooltip span** element to the earlier span elements and handle the visibility of tooltip in css using hover.

Refer to this stackblitz link for better understanding:
[stackblitz innerhtml tooltip](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ntddth?file=src/app/app.component.ts)